# bootstrap 3 right element on top of left element in smaller screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible in bootstrap 3 when two elements are side by side. In smaller screen right element goes on top of the left element? Usually right element goes underneath of the left element.

Comment: I am tot totally sure, you can try with js, but I am almost sure this is not included in bs3 docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the column ordering feature:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">Right Column</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12">Left Column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It couldn't be with 12 column (one underneath of the other). Like this: <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">Right Column</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12">Left Column</div>
</div>

Comment: Yes, you are correct I will edit the answer. If it helped you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: You're missing one dash; needs to be: `col-xs-push-12`

Comment: Good catch @cvrebert. Fixed it.